# MYSQL: unexpected result from select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database tracking product batch numbers, the format of a batch is as follows.

field: `outerbatchcode`
example: `GA1509007-3`

I have a select that has worked for over a year on thousands of records to find the current highest batch.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(outerbatchcode, 10, length(outerbatchcode)-9) AS UNSIGNED)) AS batchcode
FROM batchtracking
where prodid = 201
```

This would normally pull back 1, 2 etc

in this and a few other cases at present it is pulling back the following style

```
18446744073709551615
```

Any ideas why it isn't pulling back 3 as would be expected?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data from the table?

Comment: Very simple you cast `-3` to unsigned integer. **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/35447/0)**

Comment: the data in the post is actual data.

Comment: Try `select outerbatchcode, length(outerbatchcode)-9), CAST(SUBSTRING(outerbatchcode, 10, ...` and see what you get.

Comment: @lad2025 I don't quite understand that i'm afraid, any simpler version?

Comment: When you do SUBSTRING you get  `-3` then `-3` is convereted to unsigned integer so you get MAX_INT -3

Comment: The *underlying* problem is of course that you store a composed string rather than the separate information, i.e. the string 'GA1509007' in one column and the running number 3 in another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is clearly that your code is not in your expected format.  Your value is very close to the maximum value for `bigint`, which suggests that you are getting a negative value.  The negative value presumably comes from the hyphen in the formatted code.  In other words, you are converting "-3" to an unsigned rather than "3".

I would suggest using `substring_index()` instead:

```
select max(cast(substring_index(outerbatchcode, '-', -1) as unsigned))
from batchtracking
where prodid = 201;
```

Comment: I must have missed the code moving up to 11 characters instead of 10, much better solution here than I had!